# NMAKE clean with PowerShell and UNC paths

Tags: c, powershell, makefile, nmake

I am experiencing some problems when trying to clean my current build using NMAKE, PowerShell and UNC paths. In the nmakefile, my clean target looks like this:

```
clean: del obj\* /Q
```

This should delete all files from the "obj" directory when typing "nmake clean". However, it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
CMD.exe was started with the specified path
UNC paths are not supported
Using the Windows directory instead
System cannot find the specified file
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'del' : return code '0x1'
```

**Seriously? It's falling back to the Windows directory?** Thank God I didn't have a

```
del *
```

in the clean target. After the initial shock (and relief that I didn't use the above command) I tried to find another way of cleaning my "obj" directory from the nmakefile. I tried to use PowerShell commands instead of "del", i.e. like this:

```
clean: Remove-Item obj/* -Recurse -Force
```

However, this still doesn't work. NMAKE is still trying to start CMD.exe and then run "Remove-Item" from there which of course doesn't work. And it still does this "fallback-to-Windows-directory-in-case-of-UNC-path" horror!

Could anybody tell me how I am supposed to implement an nmake clean target that works with PowerShell and UNC paths?

Also, is there a way to turn off this falling-back-to-Windows-directory horror?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `nmake` has no native support for PowerShell, so you need to run `PowerShell.exe` with parameters, like this:

```
clean: powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Remove-Item obj/* -Recurse -Force"
```

In case anything goes wrong, try it first with something harmless:

```
clean: powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem /* -Recurse -Force"
```